# Cleaning up messy corner lines?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

I'm kind of new to this stack exchange thing so please bear with me!

Anyway, I'm trying make a ribbon on Illustrator.

[image: Overview of the shape I'm making]

Upon making this ribbon from basic shapes and combining them with the Shape builder tool, I end up getting these really messy/jagged corners, and I have no idea what to do and how to fix it...

Any tips/advice/tricks on fixing this would be hugely appreciated! :)

(I'm alright with using Illustrator so feel free to throw complicated lingo at me!)

[image: Well...]

Also, just in case you wanted to the know the shapes that make up this ribbon...

[image: Shapes]

Thanks again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is another solution: Change the stroke corners to rounded

**Square:**
[image: square]

**Rounded:**
[image: rounded]

Of course, that is assuming you are ok with actually having a rounded corner there as opposed to completely square.

Comment: This or changing the "Align Stroke" to `Inside` is probably the easiest options.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have these shapes:

[image]

Match the shapes as close as you can, Select them, then go to Object->Expand

Next, evoke Pathfinder and press Unite:

[image]

Now, you can adjust (remove and move) any anchor point to create perfect corners -

[image] + Anchor point remove tool (press "-") [image]

Will give you this corner -

[image]

There are a lot of other ways to achieve this task.

Comment: Interesting, I myself have never really delved into the "Object" context menu. (Thanks for showing me this!) Just wondering, what does the Object > Expand do exactly? Is it the same as Object >  Path > Outline Path?