# Creating a sharp corner with three thick lines?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have three thick lines that intersect, and I'd like to make the corner sharp. I've tried the solution [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31988/cleaning-up-messy-corner-lines), but since I'm adding the sharp corner and not simply removing stray lines, it's a little messy; is there a more precise way to do this instead of eyeballing the vertical position of the anchor point?

[image: corner not sharp]

Answer (score 7):

You need to joint the outer shape. So select the leftmost and rightmost line and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> to apply join (or rmb and select from popup menu or form edit menu).

[image]

**Image 1**: Timelapse of joining the outer shape.